# How can I keep all key-value pairs from a JSON document containing objects with duplicate keys?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, duplicates, deserialization

I'm having a little trouble in getting this done correctly but I have data that looks like this:

```
{  
      "completedProtocol": "Extract",
      "map": [
        {
          "sampleIDsIn": [{ "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024254" }, { "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024255" }, { "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024256"}],
          "sampleIDsOut": ["claritySample3", "claritySample4", "claritySample5"],
          "files":["http://fileserver.net/path/to/datafile3"]
        }
      ],
      "map": [
        {
          "sampleIDsIn": [{ "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024258" }, { "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024259" }, { "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024260"}],
          "sampleIDsOut": ["claritySample3", "claritySample4", "claritySample5"],
          "files":["http://fileserver.net/path/to/datafile3"]
        }
      ]
    }
```

and I want to convert it to this:

```
[{"map": [
        {
          "sampleIDsIn": [{ "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024254" }, { "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024255" }, { "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024256"}],
          "sampleIDsOut": ["claritySample3", "claritySample4", "claritySample5"],
          "files":["http://fileserver.net/path/to/datafile3"]
        }
      ]},
{"map":[
        {
          "sampleIDsIn": [{ "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024258" }, { "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024259" }, { "clarityId": "claritySample1", "espId": "ESP024260"}],
          "sampleIDsOut": ["claritySample3", "claritySample4", "claritySample5"],
          "files":["http://fileserver.net/path/to/datafile3"]
        }
      ]}]
```

My code so far is:

```
import json

obj = json.loads(body)
newData = [dct for dct in obj if 'map' in dct]
```

but this only returns:

```
[u'map']
```

If I just use `json.loads` on the body it only returns the second value of `map`, overwriting the first value.

**Note:** I want a sequence of single-item dicts; I *don't* want to collect the values together under a single key.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom `object_pairs_hook` function to force `json.loads()` to return a list of single-item dicts, rather than a single dict with duplicate keys overwritten:

```
import json

def keep_duplicates(ordered_pairs):
    result = []
    for key, value in ordered_pairs:
        result.append({key: value})
    return result
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load):

> *object_pairs_hook* is an optional function that will be called with the
>   result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs.
>   The return value of *object_pairs_hook* will be used instead of the
>   `dict`. This feature can be used to implement custom decoders that rely
>   on the order that the key and value pairs are decoded (for example,
>   `collections.OrderedDict()` will remember the order of insertion). If
>   *object_hook* is also defined, the object_pairs_hook takes priority.

Usage:

```
>>> json.loads('{"a": 1, "a": 2, "a": 3}', object_pairs_hook=keep_duplicates)
[{u'a': 1}, {u'a': 2}, {u'a': 3}]
```

In your case, since you apparently aren't interested in anything except `"map"` keys, you can filter the results afterwards:

```
all_data = json.loads(body, object_pairs_hook=keep_duplicates)
map_data = [x for x in all_data if 'map' in x]
```

… which will get you exactly the result specified in your question.